# How to rebuild parent widget on dispose of child widget?

Tags: flutter, widget

I upgraded the version of Flutter in my desktop.

At the same time, there was a problem that was not before.

Before, The parent statefulwidget(scaffold) was re-built when the user popped the child statefulwidget(scaffold in pushed route).

However, now(1.20.3) It doesn't.

So, is there any update to call build method of the parent widget on dispose of child widget?

I think that changing the version of Flutter to the old one is not a progressive approach.
(And I didn't check the version in fact..)

Comment: Try using a void callback inside the dispose, then set state inside the parent ? This is a example of how to use VoidCallback https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-widget-communication

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It should be a way. I handled this issue by using "then()" method of "Navigator.push()" and passing context of the parent widget to call bloc provider of the parent. I'm going to think about what i have to use between those two ways. It seems like the way you suggested is better than mine. thanks a lot for the new way!